# Can't launch Qt project, exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: c++, qt, runtime-error, overriding

The project is set up correctly I guess, I've got no build errors and all classes are being recognized. The problem is that when I add the line

`ui->lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);`

that should set the `completer` for my `lineEdit` the application won't launch and it shows an output error

`Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

Here are the project files

`.pro`

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.1) Thu Jul 18 13:48:43 2019
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = "Laboratorio 5"
INCLUDEPATH += .
QT += gui core widgets

# The following define makes your compiler warn you if you use any
# feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

# Input
HEADERS += DiskUsageAnalyzer.h FileSystemModel.h
FORMS += DiskUsageAnalyzer.ui
SOURCES += DiskUsageAnalyzer.cpp FileSystemModel.cpp main.cpp
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "DiskUsageAnalyzer.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    DiskUsageAnalyzer diskUsageAnalyzer;

    diskUsageAnalyzer.show();

    return application.exec();
}
```

`FileSystemModel.h`

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class FileSystemModel : public QFileSystemModel {

    Q_OBJECT


public:
    explicit FileSystemModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;

};
```

`FileSystemModel.cpp`

```
#include "FileSystemModel.h"

FileSystemModel::FileSystemModel(QObject *parent) : QFileSystemModel(parent) {


}

QVariant FileSystemModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole && index.column() == 0) {
        QString path  = QDir::toNativeSeparators(filePath(index));
        if (path.endsWith(QDir::separator()))
            path.chop(1);
        return path;
    }
    return QFileSystemModel::data(index, role);
}
```

`DiskUsageAnalyzer.h`

```
#include "ui_DiskUsageAnalyzer.h"
#include "FileSystemModel.h"


class DiskUsageAnalyzer : public QMainWindow {

    Q_OBJECT

private:
    Ui_DiskUsageAnalyzer *ui;
    FileSystemModel *dirModel;
    QCompleter *completer;

public:
    explicit DiskUsageAnalyzer(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~DiskUsageAnalyzer() override;

public slots:


signals:


};
```

`DiskUsageAnalyzer.cpp`

```
#include "DiskUsageAnalyzer.h"

DiskUsageAnalyzer::DiskUsageAnalyzer(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    ui = new Ui::DiskUsageAnalyzer;
    dirModel = new FileSystemModel(this);
    dirModel->setRootPath("");
    completer = new QCompleter(this);
    ui->lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

DiskUsageAnalyzer::~DiskUsageAnalyzer() {
    delete ui;
}
```

Sorry for not providing a minimal reproducible example but I'm new to Qt and I have no clue on how to reduce all files at minimum.

Comment: I guess that `ui->setupUi(this);` should be called before `ui->lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);`.

Comment: @rafix07 you're right and now is launching. I have doubts about parents for the private pointers about my `DiskUsageAnalyzer` class. Do I need to specify the `parent` for all these objects created into the constructor? For example, shouldn't be `completer` the `parent` of the `FileSystemModel` object?

Comment: Not correct. If you don't set a parent, you do not automatically leak memory. You are simply responsible for the memory that is allocated by the object. I.e. you must **delete** it yourself, or use the object's deleteLater() function.

Comment: I will rephrase that. `Qt` has a relationship where when a parent is freed it will automatically free all children of that parent that are still in existence. If you fail to set the parent you will have to manage the freeing of the widgets yourself otherwise there will be a memory leak.